# How to calculate uptime rate comparing timestamps by status

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have a table where I record http calls. Here's how my table looks like:

| callTimestamp | httpStatus | endpoint |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-01 06:00:00 | 200 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 |
| 2021-04-01 10:21:11 | 200 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 |
| 2021-04-01 10:25:00 | 500 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 |
| 2021-04-01 11:33:15 | 200 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 |
| 2021-04-01 11:34:31 | 200 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 |
| 2021-04-01 11:35:22 | 500 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 |
| 2021-04-01 12:22:54 | 200 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 |
| 2021-04-01 10:21:11 | 200 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint2 |
| 2021-04-01 10:25:32 | 500 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint2 |
| 2021-04-01 10:59:12 | 200 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint2 |

I need to calculate the uptime rate, which is:

1. The total uptime rate (100%) in seconds is **TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), MIN(callTimestamp)))**
2. Need to calculate the (downtime) difference between the record with httpStatus 500 and it's subsequent with httpStatus 200 grouped by endpoint.
   From the example above for endpoint1, I have two ocurrences:

   2021-04-01 11:33:15 - 2021-04-01 10:25:00 = 4095 seconds

   2021-04-01 12:22:54 - 2021-04-01 11:35:22 = 2852 seconds

**Example of expected result**
*Considering*
MIN(callTimestamp) = 2021-04-01 06:00:00
NOW() = 2021-04-01 22:00:00

TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), MIN(callTimestamp))) = 57600 seconds (this is my 100%)

endpoint1 = 57600 - 6947 = 50563 seconds uptime
endpoint2 = 57600 - 2020 = 55580 seconds uptime

| uptimeRate | endpoint |
| --- | --- |
| 87.93 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 |
| 96.49 | https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint2 |

I don't have idea of how to calc the downtime by endpoint.

Any ideas of how could I do this?

P.S: I'm using MySQL 8.0.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()over()` to calculate next  `callTimestamp` and `min()over()` window function to select minimum `callTimestamp`. Then with group by and aggregation you can get what you are looking for.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table mytable(callTimestamp datetime,   httpStatus int, endpoint varchar(100));
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 10:21:11',200,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1');
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 10:25:00',500,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1');
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 11:33:15',200,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1');
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 11:34:31',200,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1');
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 11:35:22',500,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1');
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 12:22:54',200,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1');
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 10:21:11',200,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint2');
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 10:25:32',500,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint2');
 insert into mytable values('2021-04-01 10:59:12',200,  'https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint2');
```

Query:

```
 select endpoint, 100*(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), max(mincalltime)))-sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(nexttime, calltimestamp))))/ TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), max(mincalltime))) uptimeRate
 
 
 from
 (select *,lead(calltimestamp)over (partition by endpoint order by calltimestamp)nexttime,
 min(calltimestamp)over(partition by endpoint order by calltimestamp) mincalltime
 from mytable 
 )t
 where httpstatus=500
 group by endpoint
```

Output:

| endpoint | uptimeRate |
| --- | --- |
| https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint1 | 98.8895 |
| https://someserver/someapi/v1/endpoint2 | 99.6771 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f8f1bdf791e4caba64f7252f3c6ad8c)*